# How to solve Laplace and Poisson's equation using Monte Carlo simulation for a parallel plate cpacitor?

Tags: capacitor, matlab, monte-carlo

I know how to solve for voltage and field using Laplace and Poisson equation for a simple parallel plate capacitor. But I cannot get any idea on how to proceed with Monte-Carlo simulation using MatLab for the same.
Please help me.

Comment: can you show your working out and what you have so far?

Comment: I cannot understand how to use random walk so as to simulate monte carlo for the 1dimensional capacitor?